# Why are emblems disabled in the unity launcher?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

I have seen screenshots with emblems and bug reports like [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libunity/+bug/735920) suggest that emblems were there at some point but they no longer work and there does not seem to be a way to set them in the libunity api.  Is this an intentional decision or a temporary situation until they work correctly?  Emblems would be useful in particular for dropbox and ubuntu one. Anyone have any info?

Answer (score 1):

According to the logs of this [Unity Q+A session](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MeetingLogs/appdevweek1104/UnityQ%26A), emblems/badges were removed (likely a design decision), while counters and progress bars are still present.

Comment: What kind of "design decision" removes something so useful? 
Do you know of any way to restore them?

Comment: Yes I don't understand since from comments I have read it seams they were pretty much working, I would love them especially for syncing emblems on dropbox, or ubuntu one.

Comment: Is this still true? Or have they added back support? Thanks